# I do not commit and the state is updated in Vuex

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have a bit frustrating problem, result that I have a select / option where I choose an item and then a modal is opened and just by clicking on Add / update to table, it just commits to the state "itemstabla", but result that when I give it to edit item in the table and the model is opened and I change, for example, quantity to another digit, the state "itemstabla" is updated without executing the commit, it should only be done when clicking on the modal button.

[image]

My store:

```js
    let store = {
      state: {
        token: localStorage.getItem('access_token') || null,
        items: [],
        itemstabla: [],
        monedas: [],
        impuestos: [],
        venta: [],
        estadotienda: '',
      },
      getters: {
        loggedIn(state) {
          return state.token !== null
        },
      },
      mutations: {
        EliminarItemTabla(state, item) {
          var index = state.itemstabla.findIndex(c => c.id == item);
          state.itemstabla.splice(index, 1);
       },
        retrieveToken(state, token) {
          state.token = token
        },
        setmonedas(state, monedas) {
          state.monedas = monedas
        },
        setventa(state, venta) {
          state.venta = venta
        },
        setitemstabla(state, items) {
          let found = state.itemstabla.find(item => item.id == items.id);
          
          if(found) {
            if(items.accion=='agregar') {
              found.cantidad = parseInt(found.cantidad) + parseInt(items.cantidad)
            }  
            else {
              found.cantidad = parseInt(items.cantidad)
            }
          }
          else {
            state.itemstabla.push(items)
          }
          
        },
        actualizaritemstabla(state) {
          state.itemstabla.forEach(function (item) {
            if ((state.venta.moneda_id == 'S/' && item.moneda == 'S/') || (state.venta.moneda_id == '$' && item.moneda == '$')) {
              item.precio = parseFloat(item.precio).toFixed(2)
            }
            else if(state.venta.moneda_id == '$' && item.moneda == 'S/') {
              item.moneda = '$'
              item.precio = parseFloat(parseFloat(item.precio) / parseFloat(state.venta.tipocambio)).toFixed(2)
            }
            else if(state.venta.moneda_id == 'S/' && item.moneda == '$') {
              item.moneda = 'S/'
              item.precio = parseFloat(parseFloat(item.precio) * parseFloat(state.venta.tipocambio)).toFixed(2)
            }
          });
        },
        setimpuestos(state, impuestos) {
          state.impuestos = impuestos
        },
        setmonedaid(state, moneda_id) {
          state.venta.moneda_id = moneda_id
        },
        settipocambio(state, tipocambio) {
          state.venta.tipocambio = tipocambio
        },
        destroyToken(state) {
          state.token = null
        }
      },
      actions: {
        retrieveToken(context, credentials) {
    
          return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            axios.post('/api/login', {
              username: credentials.username,
              password: credentials.password,
            })
              .then(response => {
                const token = response.data.access_token
                localStorage.setItem('access_token', token)
                context.commit('retrieveToken', token)
    
                resolve(response)
              })
              .catch(error => {
                reject(error)
              })
          })
    
        },
        destroyToken(context) {
          
          if (context.getters.loggedIn){
            
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
              axios.post('/api/logout', '', {
                  headers: { Authorization: "Bearer " + context.state.token }
                })
                .then(response => {
                  localStorage.removeItem('access_token')
                  context.commit('destroyToken')
      
                  resolve(response)
                })
                .catch(error => {
                  localStorage.removeItem('access_token')
                  context.commit('destroyToken')
    
                  reject(error)
                })
            })
    
          }
        }
      }
    }
    
    export default store
```

My file Vue:

```html
    <template>
    <div>
        <!-- MODAL PARA EDITAR ITEM -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="editarItem" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="editarItem" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        
                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Editar ítem</h5>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="cantidadEdit" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label col-form-label-sm font-weight-bold">Cantidad</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <input v-model="item.cantidad" type="number" class="form-control text-center font-weight-bold h2" min="1" tabindex="1" onfocus="this.select();">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="itemEdit" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label col-form-label-sm">Stock</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control text-center font-weight-bold h2" v-model="item.stock" disabled>
    
                            </div>
                        </div>
    
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="precioEdit" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label col-form-label-sm">Precio unitario<small class="text-muted" id="porcentajefinalprecio">+ {{item.primer_margen}}%</small></label>
                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                <input v-model="item.precio" type="text" class="form-control font-weight-bold" tabindex="2" onfocus="this.select();">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label col-form-label-sm">Tipo de impuesto</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                
                                <select v-model="item.impuesto" class="imp custom-select" id="imp">
                                    <option v-for="imp in impuestos" v-bind:key="imp.id" v-bind:value="imp.id">{{ imp.nombre }}</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="precioTotalEdit" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label col-form-label-sm">Subtotal <small id="simboloparatodos" class="text-muted">{{item.moneda_id}}</small></label>
                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                <input type="text" v-model="subtotal" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="precioTotalEdit" onfocus="this.select();" readonly>
                            </div>
                        </div>
    
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="precioigvEdit" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label col-form-label-sm">I.G.V. </label>
                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                <input type="text"  v-model="igv" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="precioigvEdit" readonly>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="descuentoEdit" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label col-form-label-sm">Descuento</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                <input v-model="item.descuento" type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="descuentoEdit" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top" data-html="true" data-content="Para montos. Ej: 10<br>Para porcentajes agrega %. Ej: 10%" data-trigger="hover" tabindex="4" onfocus="this.select();">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="precioSubtotalEdit" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label col-form-label-sm">Total <small id="simboloparatodos" class="text-muted">{{ moneda_id }}</small></label>
                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                <input v-model="total" type="text" class="form-control font-weight-bold" id="precioSubtotalEdit" value="0" tabindex="5" onfocus="this.select();">
                            </div>
                        </div>
    
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="precio20Edit" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label col-form-label-sm">Precio <small class="text-muted" id="porcentajeinicial">+ {{item.primer_margen}}%</small></label>
                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                <div id="margeninicialx">{{ item.masprimermargen }}</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="precio35Edit" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label col-form-label-sm">Precio <small class="text-muted" id="porcentajefinal">+ {{item.segundo_margen}}%</small></label>
                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                <div id="margenfinalx"> {{ item.massegundomargen }}</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="itemEdit" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label col-form-label-sm">Item</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                <small id="marcaEdit">{{ item.marca }}</small> <a href="#" title="" target="_blank" id="itemEdit" style="text-transform: capitalize;">{{ item.nombre }}</a><br><span class="text-muted small" title="códigos" id="codigoedit" v-for="cod in codigos" v-bind:key="cod.id">{{ cod.nombre_codigo }}-{{ cod.pivot.nombre }}<br></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" tabindex="5" @click="anadiritem">Añadir</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
         <!-- FIN DE MODAL PARA EDITAR ITEM -->
        
         <!-- SECCION SELECCIONAR ITEM Y AGREGAR A LA TABLA -->
          
        <div class="">
            <div class="input-group input-group-sm mb-3">
                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                    <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></span>
                </div>
                <div class="prefetch">
                    <input type="text" id="item" class="form-control typeahead" placeholder="Buscar item (Ctrl+.)" v-model.trim="q" @keyup.enter="buscaritem">
    
                </div>
                <div class="input-group-append">
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" id="button-addon2" disabled></button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-sm table-responsive-md text-nowrap mt-3" id="detailFactura">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Ítem</th>
                    <th class="text-right">Cnt.</th>
                    <th class="text-right">Costo U.</th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th class="text-right text-nowrap">
                        SubTotal
                    </th>
                    <th class="text-right text-nowrap">
                        I.G.V
                    </th>
                    <th class="text-right text-nowrap"><span class="text-muted">
                            Total
                            <div id="monedaText"></div>
                        </span></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
               
                <tr v-for="itemtabla in itemstabla" v-bind:key="itemtabla.id">
                    <td class="overflow-hidden" style="max-width: 299px; text-overflow: ellipsis"><a href="#" title="" target="_blank">{{ item.nombre }}</a> <small class="text-muted">({{ itemtabla.marca }})</small> </td>
                    <td class="text-right"><small class="text-muted mr-1" title="Unidades">{{ itemtabla.unidad }}</small>{{ itemtabla.cantidad }}</td>
                    <td class="text-right">{{ itemtabla.precio }}</td>
                    <td class="text-right">
                        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="edt" v-on:click="editaritem(itemtabla)"><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt mr-2"></i></a>
                        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="borrar" v-on:click="deleteitem(itemtabla.id)"><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i></a>
                    </td>
                    <td class="text-right">{{ preciosegunmoneda(itemtabla.precio, itemtabla.moneda, itemtabla.cantidad, itemtabla.impuesto, itemtabla.descuento).subtotal }}</td>
                    <td class="text-right">{{ preciosegunmoneda(itemtabla.precio, itemtabla.moneda, itemtabla.cantidad, itemtabla.impuesto, itemtabla.descuento).igv }}</td>
                    <td class="text-right">{{ preciosegunmoneda(itemtabla.precio, itemtabla.moneda, itemtabla.cantidad, itemtabla.impuesto, itemtabla.descuento).total }}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
            <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" class="text-right" id="cantidadItems">{{ itemstabla.length }} </td>
                    <td class="small font-weight-bolder">ítem(s)</td>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
        </table>
          <!-- FIN DE SECCION SELECCIONAR ITEM Y AGREGAR A LA TABLA -->
    </div>
    </template>
    
    <script>
    import {
        required,
        minLength,
        maxLength,
        between
    } from 'vuelidate/lib/validators'
    import Bloodhound from 'corejs-typeahead/dist/bloodhound';
    import typeahead from 'corejs-typeahead/dist/typeahead.jquery';
    export default {
        name: 'tabla-item',
        props: {
            tienda: Number,
        },
        data() {
            return {
                resource: 'venta',
                error: false,
                submitStatus: null,
                isLoading: false,
                fullPage: true,
                q: '',
                suggestions: null,
                item: {},
    
            }
        },
        created() {
    
        },
        mounted() {
            let contextoVue = this
            // Cargar los datos del typeahead en items
            this.suggestions = new Bloodhound({
                datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('title'),
                queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
                identify: function (item) {
                    return item.id;
                },
                remote: {
                    url: '/item/records/' + this.tienda + '/' + '%QUERY',
                    wildcard: '%QUERY'
                }
            });
    
            let inputEl = $('.prefetch input');
            inputEl.typeahead({
                minLength: 1,
                highlight: true,
            }, {
                name: 'suggestions',
                source: this.suggestions,
                limit: 20,
                display: 'label',
                templates: {
                    suggestion: (data) => {
                        let codigos = data.codigos
                        let nuevoscodigos = ""
                        codigos.forEach(function (valor, indice, array) {
                            nuevoscodigos = nuevoscodigos + valor.pivot.nombre + ','
                        });
                        let nuevoprecio = ((parseFloat(contextoVue.preciosegunmoneda(data.precio, data.moneda,'1',data.impuesto_id).precio) * parseFloat(data.primer_margen) / 100) + parseFloat(contextoVue.preciosegunmoneda(data.precio, data.moneda,'1',data.impuesto_id).precio)).toFixed(2)
                        return `<div class="ss-suggestion">
                        <div class="codigos">
                        ${data.nombre_marca} <span title="Código global"> - ${nuevoscodigos}</span>
                        <span title="Código de barras"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="searchproducto" style="text-transform: capitalize;">
                        <strong>${data.nombre}</strong>
                        </div>
                        <div class="d-flex mt-1"><div class="searchprice text-primary">${contextoVue.moneda_id} 
                        <span id="pricechange">${nuevoprecio}</span></div>
                        <div class="searchstock flex-grow-1 text-danger"><b>Stock</b>: 
                        <b style="color: red;">${data.stock}</b><b></b></div></div></div>`;
    
                    }
                }
            });
            // Cuando se hace click en un item 
            $('.prefetch input').bind('typeahead:selected', function (evt, suggestion) {
                $('#editarItem').modal('show')
                let preciosegunmoneda = ((parseFloat(contextoVue.preciosegunmoneda(suggestion.precio, suggestion.moneda, '1', suggestion.impuesto_id).precio) * parseFloat(suggestion.primer_margen) / 100) + parseFloat(contextoVue.preciosegunmoneda(suggestion.precio, suggestion.moneda, '1', suggestion.impuesto_id).precio)).toFixed(2)
                let massegundomargen = ((parseFloat(contextoVue.preciosegunmoneda(suggestion.precio, suggestion.moneda, '1', suggestion.impuesto_id).precio) * parseFloat(suggestion.segundo_margen) / 100) + parseFloat(contextoVue.preciosegunmoneda(suggestion.precio, suggestion.moneda, '1', suggestion.impuesto_id).precio)).toFixed(2)
                contextoVue.item = {
                    id: suggestion.id,
                    stock: suggestion.stock,
                    nombre: suggestion.nombre,
                    precio: preciosegunmoneda,
                    marca: suggestion.nombre_marca,
                    impuesto: suggestion.impuesto_id,
                    primer_margen: suggestion.primer_margen,
                    segundo_margen: suggestion.segundo_margen,
                    masprimermargen: preciosegunmoneda,
                    massegundomargen: massegundomargen,
                    codigos: suggestion.codigos,
                    cantidad: '1',
                    descuento: '0',
                    moneda: contextoVue.moneda_id,
                    unidad: suggestion.nombre_unidad,
                }
    
            });
            // Fin typeahead items
    
        },
        updated() {
    
        },
    
        computed: {
            total()  {
                return this.item.precio *  this.item.cantidad -  this.item.descuento
            },
            igv()  {
            if(this.item.impuesto=="1") {
                        return (parseFloat(this.total) * 18/100).toFixed(2)
                    }
                    else {
                        return 0
                    }
            },
            subtotal()  {
                return (parseFloat(this.total) - this.igv).toFixed(2)
            },
            tipocambio: {
                get() {
                    return this.$store.state.venta.tipocambio
                },
                set(value) {
                    this.$store.commit('settipocambio', value)
                }
            },
            moneda_id: {
                get() {
                    return this.$store.state.venta.moneda_id
                },
                set(value) {
                    this.$store.commit('setmonedaid', value)
                }
            },
            itemstabla: {
                get() {
                    return this.$store.state.itemstabla
                },
                
            },
            impuestos: {
                get() {
                    return this.$store.state.impuestos
                },
            },
    
        },
        watch: {
        moneda_id: function (val) {
            //this.$store.commit('actualizaritemstabla')
        },
        },
        methods: {
            submit() {},
            preciosegunmoneda(precio, moneda, cantidad, impuesto, descuento) {
                let total,nuevoprecio,subtotal,igv = 0
                if ((this.moneda_id == 'S/' && moneda == 'S/') || (this.moneda_id == '$' && moneda == '$')) {
                    nuevoprecio = parseFloat(precio).toFixed(2)
                    total = parseFloat((parseFloat(precio) * cantidad) - descuento).toFixed(2)
                    igv = parseFloat((parseFloat(total) * (impuesto=='1' ? 18/100 : 0))).toFixed(2)
                    subtotal = parseFloat(total - igv).toFixed(2)
                    return {precio: nuevoprecio, total: total, igv: igv, subtotal: subtotal  }
                } 
                else if (this.moneda_id == 'S/' && moneda == '$') {
                    nuevoprecio = parseFloat(precio * this.tipocambio).toFixed(2)
                    total = parseFloat((parseFloat(precio * this.tipocambio) * cantidad) - descuento).toFixed(2)
                    igv = parseFloat((parseFloat(total) * (impuesto=='1' ? 18/100 : 0))).toFixed(2)
                    subtotal = parseFloat(total - igv).toFixed(2)
                    return {precio: nuevoprecio, total: total, igv: igv, subtotal: subtotal }
                }
                else if (this.moneda_id == '$' && moneda == 'S/') {
                    nuevoprecio = parseFloat(precio / this.tipocambio).toFixed(2)
                    total = parseFloat((parseFloat(precio / this.tipocambio) * cantidad) - descuento).toFixed(2)
                    igv = parseFloat((parseFloat(total) * (impuesto=='1' ? 18/100 : 0))).toFixed(2)
                    subtotal = parseFloat(total - igv).toFixed(2)
                    return {precio: nuevoprecio, total: total, igv: igv, subtotal: subtotal }
                }
            },
            deleteitem(i) {
                this.$store.commit('EliminarItemTabla', i);
            },
            editaritem(item) {
                $('#editarItem').modal('show')
                this.item = item
            },
            anadiritem(event) {
                 $('#editarItem').modal('hide')
                 this.$store.commit('setitemstabla', this.item )
            },
    
        },
        validations: {
            form: {
                nombre_codigo: {
                    required,
                },
            }
        }
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: I found that when I edit an item, I pass the reactive object of the state to it, so it will be modified without changing the state.

Comment: So by copying the object and passing it to the modal, when modifying it would no longer have reactivity and it would only change the state when clicking:

const copy = Object.assign ({}, item, this.item)
this.item = copy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the use of `editaritem` like you do, I think you're actually passing the item itself, so it gets modified as it's a reference.

```js
    editaritem(item) {
        $('#editarItem').modal('show')
        this.item = { ...item } // or some way to copy the object 
    }
```

And after you finish edit, perform the actual update of the edited object.